# How to close HP Audio switch interface without restarting?

Tags: user-interface

[image]

How do I make this HP Audio switch interface go away without restarting my computer?

Comment: Have you looked in Admin Tools, Services?  Also download and run Autoruns (SysInternals) and delete all occurrences of the device.

Comment: Have you tried disabling the unwanted device inside device manager?